# Styles for current item with anchor links with absolute path in Wordpress menu

Tags: wordpress, menu, anchor

I decided to create absolute paths with anchors in the menu of wordpress.

```
<a href="http://mywebsite.com#item1">Item1</a>
<a href="http://mywebsite.com#item2">Item2</a>
```

It works fine , however, all items are showed active because I'm using absolute paths.  How can I detect the element active and all the elements are not showed as active at the same time.

Thanks in advance.

Thanks.

Comment: You need some jquery work here. Through jquery script, you can get the current URL from jquery and you can add an active class on the respective menu item. Let me know you need code for this.

Comment: If you're doing it custom, why not just add some custom classes as well?

Comment: I put /#item1 and /#item2 and all of the items are showed active.  I need only the current item be showed active.  Yes, I need c ode for this, I thought is solved and not.  Thanks.